# Resizing Partitions

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I cannot resize the HD of a new Mac Mini.  The Mac HD shows 700+ GB on one partition with Yosemite on it and another partition of 200+ GB named "Free Space" and I cannot figure out how it got there.

The output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         730.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Jude                   *730.2 GB   disk1
                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             6D73517B-FBE6-40CD-A14B-2C6F9DF3A8DC
                             Unencrypted
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS BU2                     249.7 GB   disk2s2
```

Comment: Please upload a screenshot properly. Also open Terminal.app and enter `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` each followed by the enter key, copy the outputs and add it to your question by editing it.

Comment: I cannot get the screen shots uploaded as screen shots.  Ia there a trick to it?

Comment: hmm click 'edit' at the bottom of your question. Choose the passage in the editable text field where to place the pic: [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/adv1h.jpg). Click on it and you will be asked to link a picture already online or upload one from your computer. Please also add the output of `diskutil cs list`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you select the free space partition then hit the minus (-) button to delete it? You'll probably need to try that, then see if you can drag the border of the main partition to resize, then hit the plus (+) to create a new partition. Nothing can use the free partition, so it won't hurt to try deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resize the active partition.

You need to boot into Recovery Mode which will let you and resize the main partition. Select the whole drive then the Partition tab.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718

PS Make sure you have a Time Machine backup before doing anything.

Comment: I've tried the Recovery Disk but to no avail.  I have the screen shot(s). Cannot use the - button to delete the free space partition and the main partition will not resize.  Guess I will just take the Mini back and get another one. Looks like my only way out.  The computer works fine but.......